# How to measure web assets browser cache efficiency

Tags: performance, web, web-applications, architecture, browser-cache

Do You (smart guys :) have any idea what is the best way to measure cache efficieny of assets which are used on website (js, css, fonts etc).

How should I decide if for my website better way is (for example) to put all my JS files into one file or to seperate between some smaller files?

Many websites do it with one, two, three big files, but for example Facebook has many, many small files. It's clear that Facebook has a lot of returning visitors, so this strategy is better. But how to measure it.

I know I can check for GA and returning/new visitors ratio, but it's not very deep check. After that I still don't know which users during entering my website had some my assets in cache & which hadn't.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to make an A/B test. Implement several solutions, measure impact on your users loading speed, look at 99 or 98 percentile and you'll see which works better.

Looking to returning/new visitors data is good approach, but not reliable in case you have not so many users.

Facebook uses many files because they also use http 2.0 (SPDY). It solves many problems with delivering multiple resources, for examples this protocol allows you to gzip http headers, not only bodies as good old http 1.1.

[Look at other benefits of http 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2)